# Как бороться с ошибкой MultiDex в Unity

Tags: android, unity3d, admob, facebooksdk

Ошибка

> trouble writing output: Too many field references to fit in one dex file: 69723 max is 65536.

Используется Facebook SDK и Admob SDK, PlayServicesResolver, OneSignal, можно как то решить без участия Android Studio? Удалять библиотеки?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, нужно не лимит увеличивать, а оптимизировать зависимости.

Там при билде список зависимостей выводится и сколько каждый плагин ест. Посмотрите, что можно  урезать.

1. Удалить неиспользуемые плагины.
2. Оптимизировать текущие. К примеру, возможно, у вас там есть `google-play-services.jar`. Не надо его использовать. Уже давно возможно подключать не весь `google-play-services.jar`, а лишь его части. Это ОЧЕНЬ сильно уменьшить зависимости.
3. [Почему нету поддержки MultiDex в Unity3d](https://forum.unity.com/threads/multidex-support-on-android.325429/):

> So the biggest reason we have not added support for this in Unity is
>   because it doesn't work. Or rather it usually creates more problems
>   than it solves. Unless you are targeting only modern versions of
>   Android I would suggest you do everything in your power including
>   stripping and proguarding your code before you take the route of
>   multi-dex.
>
> If you don't believe me just checkout the *known* limitations of the
>   multi-dex library at Googles developer page:
>   https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#limitations
>
> If you have a project where you really need more than 64k references I
>   would suggest exporting to Android Studio and build the project there.

В двух словах - это слишком сложный механизм, от которого, порой, больше вреда, чем пользы.

Comment: А где можно найти jar, вижу только файлы .aar

Comment: А, ну `aar` тогда. `aar` - это тот же `jar`, только ещё с ресурсами внутри (layouts, drawables и т.д.).